# URL Rewrite Module and Folder Redirects

Tags: redirect

I am having no success using the URL Rewrite module to do folder redirects. I am trying to redirect a folder to another domain (although I've had similar problems within the same domain). For example:
test input = http://www.example.com/folder
redirect URL = http://www.otherdomain.com

**Patterns**

```
*folder will work, but it's too general (will redirect ALL subfolders with same name).
*/folder will not work even though it passes the test.
*example.com/folder will not work even though it passes the test.
\S*example.com\/folder will not work even though it passes the test.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for the redirection htaccess file?

Comment: Well, it's a Windows server, so no htaccess file.